# How to add My Wishlist link in product detail page of My Account dropdown?

Tags: magento2

Actually in My Account page I am able to see the My Wishlist link in dropdown but in Product detail page I am not able to see

Add default.xml in app/design/frontend/your-theme-namespace/yourtheme/Magento_Wishlist/layout with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Link" name="wish-list-link" after="my-account-link"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: Using above way you get my order link

Comment: @Rakesh sorry that was by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="top.links">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-wishlist-link-top" after="-" >
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">wishlist/index/index</argument>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Wishlist</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>    
    </page>
```